# Cannot GET / on node js

Tags: node.js, express

I have difficulties starting my server. I do not get any log in node.js

And when I go to localhost:5000 I get the error message: cannot GET/

````
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
const keys = require('./config/keys.js');
const app = express();```

```// route handler 
app.get(
    '/auth/google', 
    passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
    })
);

//Deployment 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT); ```


I expected the program to run in the browser. Instead I get "cannot GET/" error message
````

Comment: Where is the route handler for ```app.get("/", () =>{}) ```

Comment: Isn't that a route handler Mohamed Abu Galala? I am new here  so I'm still learning the terminologies

Comment: Check the answers @tiiso-theo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// will only be served only if you called localhost:5000/auth/google
app.get(
    '/auth/google', 
    passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
    })
);
```

If you need to get a response on `localhost:5000/` you will need to add a route handler for your app

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   console.log("Someone hit localhost:5000/"); 
   res.send('We have nothing to show yet, try to visit localhost:5000/auth/google');
});
```

You can check [Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add welcome page for testing your app you have to listen to '/'

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Welcome to Main Page');
    });
```